# Artifactory Plugin seems to ignore publishPom = false

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, artifactory

I have the following basic publishing code.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "${artifactory_contextUrl}/plugins-release"
            credentials {
                username = "${artifactory_user}"
                password = "${artifactory_password}"
            }
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:4+"
    }
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: "com.jfrog.artifactory"
    apply plugin: 'maven'
    apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
}

artifactory {
    contextUrl = "${artifactory_contextUrl}"
    publish {
        repository {
            repoKey = "${publish_repository_key}"
            username = "${artifactory_user}"
            password = "${artifactory_password}"
            maven = true
        }
    }
    resolve {
        repository {
            repoKey = "${resolve_repository_key}"
            username = "${artifactory_user}"
            password = "${artifactory_password}"
            maven = true
        }
    }
    clientConfig.timeout = 10
}

publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            artifact 'test-1.1/abc-1.1.py'
            version "1.5"
            groupId "com.example"
            artifactId "script"
        }
    }
}

artifactoryPublish {
    publications ('mavenJava')
    publishBuildInfo = false
    publishArtifacts = false
    publishPom = false
    publishIvy = false
}
```

For a test I would like not to publish BuildInfo and Pom. Despite the fact all publishing is set to false invoking

```
gradle clean generatePomFileForMavenJavaPublication artifactoryPublish
```

and observing http traffic and console output confirms that all upload is still taking place.

```
Deploying artifact: https://artifactory/publish_repository_key/com/example/script/1.5/script-1.5.py
Deploying artifact: https://artifactory/publish_repository_key/com/example/script/1.5/script-1.5.pom
Error occurred for request PUT /publish_repository_key/com/example/script/1.5/script-1.5.pom.sha1;build.name=script;build.number=1512095807403 HTTP/1.1: Read timed out.
```

In addition last error completely puzzles me.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a bug. Feel free to follow it [here](https://github.com/JFrogDev/build-info/issues/144). I'll update this answer once it's fixed.

Comment: I've just tested this with the latest Artifactory Plugin version (classpath(group: 'org.jfrog.buildinfo', name: 'build-info-extractor-gradle', version: '4.+')) and the functionality seem to working as expected. Could it be that you're using an older version of the plugin?

Comment: Still broken - even the workaround in the GitHub issue didn't work for me